# Cycles, information on how the motion vectors are calculated

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-passes

Where can I find technical information on how the cycle rendering engine calculates the vector (motion) information? Specifically the backward motion. Is it doing a backward render of each frame? And if so how does it handle something like physics?

Comment: This is not an answer, but ideally for final you'd have all physics baked, so blender would have effortless forward and backward lookup

Comment: Right. But I am curious as to how Cycles does it when it is not already baked. :(